# XGBoost - Strange results with XGBClassifier predict_proba (python)

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm doing a multi-class prediction with XBGClassifier and get strange results for probabilities (clearly not the one we could expect, very different from the one with SVM.SVC for example).

Code:

```
 clf = XGBClassifier( learning_rate=0.00005, objective='multi:softprob')
[...]
 clf.fit(X, Y, eval_metric='mlogloss')
[...]
clf.predict_proba( data)
```

All the provided probabilities are very strange:

```
INFO:root:[[0.16740549 0.16724858 0.16669136 0.1662821  0.16619198 0.16618045]]
INFO:root:[[0.16658343 0.16709101 0.16700828 0.16666834 0.16638225 0.16626666]]
INFO:root:[[0.16706458 0.16723593 0.16682376 0.16645898 0.16622521 0.16619155]]
INFO:root:[[0.1670872  0.16725858 0.16679683 0.16641934 0.16624773 0.16619037]]
INFO:root:[[0.16655219 0.1669247  0.16697693 0.16680391 0.1664368  0.16630547]]
INFO:root:[[0.16774052 0.16720766 0.16651934 0.1662414  0.16615131 0.16613977]]
INFO:root:[[0.16740549 0.16724858 0.16669136 0.1662821  0.16619198 0.16618045]]
INFO:root:[[0.16658343 0.16709101 0.16700828 0.16666834 0.16638225 0.16626666]]
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: what's your data size ? these kind of results could be because of inadequacy of data or because of some unrealistic parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to @bhaskarc's pertinent comment.

It seems your model is not learning since it's predicting the same probability for all classes.

One other reason for this might be that your learning rate is too small.

Try changing it for something bigger and re-check the predictions:

```
learning_rate=0.001
```

Also you can try playing with other parameters(max_depth, n_estimators, gamma, ...)

Comment: Hi Tina, the learning_rate was the reason. I thougth that by decreasing the learning_rate it would learn "better", I was terribly wrong..
Thanks a lot!